# How do I encode an HTTP link... something very easily with javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<a onclick="go_url(ENCODED-URL);return false;">go to this url</a>
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail to explain why you want to do this? What level of security is needed? What are you trying to achieve? For what reason can you not leave the URL encoded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`decodeURI()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeURI.asp) and [`encodeURI()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp).

> The `decodeURI()` function decodes a URI
>   encoded with the `encodeURI()` function.
>
> The `encodeURI()` function encodes a
>   string as a URI.

Unlike `escape()` and `unescape()` these functions are specifically designed to handle URI-encoding/decoding.

Comment: thanks for the edit, the URI version are what you want. escape/unescape  encodes for display

Comment: Aye. I did a roll-back on your answer (was confused there for a second) and added my edits to my own.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function go_url(url) {
   var u = '';
   for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
      u += String.fromCharCode(url.charCodeAt(i) ^ 7);
   }
   window.location.href = u;
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="go_url('ossw=((ppp)`raaf)dhj');return false;">yeah</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

encodeURI(ENCODED-URL);

Answer (score -1):

Well you can use escape() and unescape().

Comment: escape and unescape should not be used.
See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent